# How i can implement JSON patching in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

My payload is below . This payload can have around 500 fields . But when user submit a save operation we are planning to have a standard patch operation.
Trying to avoid sending a whole document when only a part has changed. How i can implement it in Mule ? Any design approach i can follow ? Any documentation or example . Please share the thoughts on how i can tackle in server side.

```
{
 "loan": {
 "loanId": 12345678,
 "loanAmount": 100,
 "processingStyle": "Standard",
 "product": {
   "prodId": "051",
   "productDescrption": "Fixed"
 },
"borrower": [
   {
    "borrower#": 1,
    "borrowerFirstName": "ALICE"
  },
  {
    "borrower#": 2,
    "borrowerFirstName": "JOHN"
  }
 ]
 }

}
```

Patch operation JSON

```
[
 { "op": "replace", "path": "/loan/loanAmount", "value": "200" },
 { "op": "add", "path": "/product/productDescrption", "value": "Fixed" },
 { "op": "remove", "path": "/borrower/2" }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Your question needs more clarity .

Comment: Basically i am looking for design approach to implement the json patching in mule 4

Comment: Added a Screen shot on my thought on how i planning to implement . Is it making sense or any better thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your backend system is capable of , that would eventually be called by the Mule API - Maybe you can use a Java library that implements JSON Patch instead of taking care of the overhead yourself. Do give these a read.. https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/put-vs-patch-vs-json-patch and https://sookocheff.com/post/api/understanding-json-patch/